# Check if user liked my page or not using page url and appId

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-like

From https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/  I got this script to show the like button in my website

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
    <script>
   (function(d, s, id) {
      var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
      if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
      js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
      js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/fr_FR/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=155899567847";
      fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
   </script>
    <div class="fb-like" data-href="http://website.com/project/hello" data-send="false" data-layout="button_count" data-width="100" data-show-faces="false"></div>
```

I only have the appId and the url, can I check is current user liked my page ?
I looked in google and I found some examples using PageId and I dont know how to get it

Answer (score 1):

`PageID` is necessary for checking that page is already liked or not from another source. If you are in the same page (your facebook page) it means there is no need to get that id as it will automatically have it from the session or somewhere else.

You can get the PAGE ID by one of the following way,

http://hellboundbloggers.com/2010/07/10/find-facebook-profile-and-page-id/

http://rieglerova.net/how-to-get-a-facebook-fan-page-id/

Comment: its a like button for a website it's not for a facebook page :/ 
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/web/